# JQuery fallback for CSS3 transition

Tags: jquery, css, transition, fallback

I'm looking for a JQuery/JS fallback for a simple CSS3 transition code.
My javascript is really basic so it's not easy for me to find and write a replacement code. I already checked out modernizr but I did not really understand a lot of the documentation.

It's an icon that uses     `transform: rotate(20deg)` when hovering over (this is no issue as it supports in IE).
But the problem is the transition, I'm using

```
  .icon{
....other css code
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
-o-transition: all 300ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
transition: all 300ms linear;
}
```

is there a JQuery fallback for this? I was thinking about `fadeIn();` but I have no idea how I would code this.
something like this?:

```
<script>$(icon).hover(function (){$(icon).fadeIn("slow");}); </script>
```

and how do I let the browser know it's a fallback so that they only pick the JQuery if it's IE?

Comment: The beauty of using CSS transitions is that if it isn't supported, the change still takes place, just not animated. I'd stick with that..

Comment: @BillyMathews yes indeed, now it blinks in IE, which is not bad, but I want to give everyone the same experience, since 35% of the people (I'm from Belgium) still use IE.

Comment: Not to mention that, in up-to-date browsers, CSS will always work faster than JS animations.

Answer (score 15):

I think you already have the answer, you should use modernizr, it is not complicated as you think, there are two ways that modernizr specify which are the features available and which are not, the first one is through a set of CSS classes in the HTML element:

```
<html class="js no-flexbox canvas canvastext postmessage no-websqldatabase ... ">
```

if it is available it will appear the name, if it is not available it will appear the name with a "no-" preffix like "no-flexbox", the second one is through javascript:

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions)
```

Modernizr has a set of boolean variables that can tell you if it is available or not, so if you want to set a fallback for your animation I would suggest that you use the Modernizr classes to specify the animation only for the browsers which has this feature:

```
.csstransitions #element{
-webkit-transition: ... ;
-moz-transition: ... ;
-o-transition: ... ;
-ms-transition: ... ;
transition: ... ;
}
```

and then create a javascript file with the variables that modernizr has checking if the feature is available, if it is not then specify the animation:

```
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions)
    $("#element").hover(function(){ $(this).animate({ ... your animation ... }, 5000); });
```

this might give you an idea how Modernizr works (I hope), anyway if you have a problem you may check this [blog post](http://mechdeveloper.com/blog/things-you-should-do-support-css3) I made a long time ago, it says something like this with some other things like CSS3PIE (this is not spam, I am just trying to help).

Comment: you might as well extend $.support if you only need to detect transitions...and by the way what effect should fadeIn have on an element that's already displayed?

Comment: Well I just wanted to show how Modernizr works, I am not sure what the animation is about, therefore I do not know what effect fadein should have on an element that is already displayed.

Comment: I know fadeIn might not be a good idea, however, my point was that Modernizr was not that complicated to use.

Comment: I have updated my answer, my point was to explain how Modernizr works, I hope it helps.

Comment: @mechdeveloper I think I almost got it, my JQuery animation works fine, it is exactly the same as the css3 one but the problem is Modernizr. I went do the download page and selected 'CSS transitions', generated the code and I saved that js file and put it in my <head>. I changed the .icon class to .csstransitions .icon and put the if statement under my div. it does not work, are there thins I have forgotten?

Comment: I have implemented this in my website before, perhaps the best thing you can do is showing your code either in a comment or in a new question, there is a simple animation in my website (http://mechdeveloper.com) that opens the door, if the browser has CSS3 transitions it will add a simple CSS class opening the door, if it is not available the door will be opened through javascript.

Comment: this is a part of the code I am using in my website;   

if(Modernizr.csstransitions)
 $(highlighted).addClass("open");
else
 $(gate).animate({top:"-100%"},2000);

Comment: I think it would be better to put that code into jsfiddle.net because it is too long.

Comment: It's just a piece of a big code but I guess that's enough to see what I did wrong or forget to place in the code

Answer (score 7):

[Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) translates jQuery animate calls to CSS3 animations and falls back to regular js for unsupported browsers.

Alternatively you can extend $.support to check for transitions [like this](https://gist.github.com/jonraasch/373874) and use jQuery animate when the test for them fails.

Comment: I think you're wrong. As stated "Transit degrades older browsers by simply not doing the transformations (rotate, scale, etc) while still doing standard CSS (opacity, marginLeft, etc) without any animation." All fallbacks have to be programmed by yourself.

Comment: @René "Fallback to frame-based animation
If you would like to fallback to classic animation when transitions aren't supported, just manually redefine .transitition to .animate."